# How Can I get the price difference in percentage in the sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have three tables

One is fruits

```
+----+--------+
| ID |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Mango  |
|  2 | Banana |
+----+--------+
```

Second is fruit_initial_price

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | fruit_id | price  |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 | 100.00 |
|  2 |        2 | 100.00 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Third is fruit_latest_price

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | fruit_id | price  |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |        1 | 120.00 |
|  2 |        2 |  80.00 |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I want the difference between fruit_initial_price and fruit_latest_price price column (in percentage and value. with nagitavie and positive sign)

Something like this

```
+----+----------+----------------+--------------------+------+
| ID | fruit_id | diff_in_amount | diff_in_percentage |      |
+----+----------+----------------+--------------------+------+
|  1 |        1 |          20.00 | +20                | +20% |
|  2 |        2 |          80.00 | -20                | -20% |
+----+----------+----------------+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: I can't see why you would store initial price in a separate table from fruit; it's a 1-1 corellation. And if a column is called '...percentage' then there's absolutely no point storing '%' in it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the difference in amount and percentage in a derived table, and then format that in an outer query:

```
SELECT ID, name,
       FORMAT(diff_in_amount, 2) AS diff_in_amount,
       diff_in_percentage,
       CONCAT(IF(diff_in_percentage > 0, '+', '-'),
              ABS(ROUND(diff_in_percentage, 1)),
              '%') AS diff_percentage
FROM (
  SELECT f.ID, f.name,
         l.price - i.price AS diff_in_amount,
         100.0 * (l.price - i.price) / i.price AS diff_in_percentage
  FROM fruits f
  JOIN fruit_initial_price i ON i.fruit_id = f.ID
  JOIN fruit_latest_price l ON l.fruit_id = f.ID
) f
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
ID  name    diff_in_amount  diff_in_percentage  diff_percentage
1   Mango   20.00           20                  +20.0%
2   Banana  -20.00          -20                 -20.0%
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p8kQyoGzrCHeosq5vUCuH6/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
 *,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR,((l.price-i.price)*100)/100)+'%' as diff_in_percentage  
from fruits f , fruit_initial_price i ,fruit_latest_price l 
where f.Id = i.fruit_id and f.Id = l.fruit_id
```